# proving two compound statement is not logically equivalent.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

$(s → (p∧ ¬r))∧(p → (r ∨q))∧s$ and $p∧ ¬r ∧q$

I have to prove that these two are not logically equivalent..
without using the truth table

I am pretty sure I have to simplify the left hand side 
and I have started from

$a → b = ¬a ∨ b$, but can't get any further.

Comment: try truth tables for p,q,r and s

Comment: @Idea the question does not allow me to use the truth table

Answer (score 1):

Consider the case s is false.
What becomes of the left hand side?
Compare with what happens to the right hand side.